# How can i make this div go to the left and not the right?

Tags: css, html

Look at this picture of it...

http://www.flickr.com/photos/91733140@N06/8329388242/in/photostream

How can i make this div go to the left and not the right?

it keeps messing up and i really need it to be fixed any ideas how i can make it work?

```
    <style type="text/css">

#body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #E0E0E0;
}

#header {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 33px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px #737373 solid;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

#container {
    width: 1205px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#box {
    width: 228px;
    height: auto;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px #5E5E5E solid;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    font-family: arial;
}

#box_title {
    width: 218px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #5E5E5E;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px #FFFFFF solid;
    float: left;
    font-family: arial;
}

#box_img {
    width: 210px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#box_options {
    width: 228px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    border-top: 1px #5E5E5E solid;
    float: left;
    font-family: arial;
```

Comment: You should make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and link to it rather than a screenshot - you'll probably get a lot more help.

Comment: this reminds me on http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin

Comment: It's not an answer, but this article explains why floats do this: http://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/ (skip to crazy float rules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to judge you by your open tabs but you seem to want a "Pinterestish" wall. This is not easy via vanilla css, may I suggest looking into jquery masonry?

http://masonry.desandro.com/

It does all the heavy lifting for you

Comment: yeah i know i was looking at it to see how they had it

Comment: Both Pinterest and Microsoft HTML Metro Apps use programmatically determined absolute positioning to layout their respective grids, so if it's good enough for them then it's probably good enough for you. Definitely a +1 for importing any capable library here; unless this is a learning experience I don't think it would be worth your while to waste time doing this yourself.